# Variáveis que funcionem em mais de um método

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Tentei fazer uma calculadora simples de console, só que eu queria criar vários métodos pra deixar bem organizado.

O problema é que no método de armazenar as variáveis, ele armazena, só que quando vai pra parte de calcular ele perde os valores das variáveis obtidas no código passado.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
public class Calculadora {

    //Declaracao de variaveis
    double num1, num2;

    double resultadoSoma, resultadoSub, resultadoMulti, resultadoDivi;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new Calculadora().run();
    }

    public void perguntarValores() {
        System.out.println("Digite o primeiro valor: ");
        num1 = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Ok, digite o segundo valor: ");
        num2 = sc.nextDouble();
    }

    public void calcular() {
        resultadoSoma = num1 + num2;
        resultadoSub = num1 - num2;
        resultadoMulti = num1 * num2;
        resultadoDivi = num1 / num2;
    }

    public void exibirResultados() {
        System.out.println("O resultado em soma foi: " + resultadoSoma);
        System.out.println("O resultado em subtracao foi: " + resultadoSub);
        System.out.println("O resultado em multiplicao foi: " + resultadoMulti);
        System.out.println("O resultado em divisao foi: " + resultadoDivi);
    }

        public void run() {
        new Calculadora().perguntarValores();
        new Calculadora().calcular();
        new Calculadora().exibirResultados();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

O problema ocorre porque você está instanciando a classe para cada chamada de método. Dessa forma, o java vai criar um objeto diferente para cada chamada dentro do método `run`, altere para esta forma:

```
 public void run() {
        Calculadoda calc = new Calculadora();
        calc.perguntarValores();
        calc.calcular();
        calc.exibirResultados();
    }
```

Comment: Ahh, muito obrigado cara!! :D funcionou.
Tenho muito o que aprender ainda :)

Comment: @Froks dá pra melhorar, exemplo, deixe a calculadora apenas para efetuar as operações matematicas, recebendo 2 parametros, ai você  captura os numeros e exibe no main.

Answer (score 9):

O problema é que está criando uma nova instância em cada operação. Eu faria de uma outra forma, mas se vai fazer desse jeito, pelo menos use sempre a mesma instância pra preservar os valores. Do jeito que está, cada operação é feita em cima de dados novos.

```
public void run() {
    Calculadora calc = new Calculadora();
    calc.perguntarValores();
    calc.calcular();
    calc.exibirResultados();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Variable2.java).

Neste caso específico nem precisa ter esta instância criada, é que a classe está confusa.

Answer (score 3):

Seu erro está neste trecho:

```
  public void run() {
        new Calculadora().perguntarValores();
        new Calculadora().calcular();
        new Calculadora().exibirResultados();
    }
```

Aqui você cria uma instância para pegar o valor, outra para calcular e outra para exibir os dados.

Para ficar mais claro:

```
  public void run() {
       Calculadora a =  new Calculadora().perguntarValores();
       Calculadora b = new Calculadora().calcular();
       Calculadora c= new Calculadora().exibirResultados();
    }
```

Cada objeto Calculadora realiza uma tarefa!

Para corrigir mude para:

```
public void run() {
        perguntarValores();
        calcular();
        exibirResultados();
    }
```

Comment: Thiago, mas os métodos não são estáticos, precisa de uma instancia de objeto.

Comment: O run também não é!  Ele se encontra no mesmo contexto dos demais métodos!  Pertence a mesma classe. Quando você cria o objeto no main , este tem o método run e os demais

Comment: Verdade! Passou despercebido esse detalhe xD

Answer (score 2):

Bom, você não precisa instanciar a classe novamente toda vez que for acessar um metodo dela, entende quando você da um "new Calculadora();" você esta criando outra instancia desse objeto na memoria, com os valores todos zerados, a forma certa de você fazer seria:

```
Calculadora calculadora = new Calculadora();
calculadora.perguntarValores();
calculadora.calcular();
calculadora.exibirResultados();
```

Desta, forma em uma unica instancia de sua classe calculadora, você acessa todos os métodos publico da mesma.

Como disse anteriormente, para cada "NEW" que você faz, é uma sessão diferente daquele objeto na memoria. então se você dar três "new Calculadora();", é como se você tivesse três calculadoras diferentes na sua mão, obviamente o que você calcula em uma calculadora, não esta na outra.